# Unable to use function passed in as parameter?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to use a function (`secondaryFunction` or `secondaryFunction2`) passed in as a parameter to `primaryFunction`. However, when I run my code below:

```
(defun secondaryFunction (param1 param2)
    NIL
)

(defun secondaryFunction2 (param1 param2))
    NIL
)

(defun primaryFunction (transition param1 param2)
    (transition param1 param2)
)


(primaryFunction 'secondaryFunction 0 0)
```

I get the following error:

> *** - EVAL: undefined function TRANSITION

This seems strange, considering that I thought that I passed in `secondaryFunction` clearly as the `transition` parameter to `primaryFunction`?

Comment: use FUNCALL, btw. there are good and easy introductions into using Lisp. Download one here: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Comment: That should help: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/functions.html#calling-functions-programmatically-funcall-and-apply

Answer (score 3):

There are separate function and value namespaces.  In `primary-function`, you get the transition function as a value (actually the symbol here).  Use `funcall` to call it:

```lisp
(defun primary-function (transition param1 param2)
  (funcall transition param1 param2))
```

Side Note:  You are using a symbol, which means that funcall calls the function with that symbol as a name in the global environment.  That's OK.  You can also pass the function itself, with the `function` special operator (which has a shorthand `#'` reader macro):

```lisp
(primary-function #'secondary-function 0 0)
```